# Meteor and AngularJS delimiters conflicts

Tags: angularjs, meteor, angularjs-directive

Meteor is using handlebars with Mustache {{}}
Angular is using interpolate with the same delimiters {{}}

Then, using AngularJS on Meteor will result in obvious conflicts.

Fortunately there is a way to change the AngularJS delimiters using for example `[[]]`:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [], function($interpolateProvider) {
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('[[');
    $interpolateProvider.endSymbol(']]');
});
```

As I know there is no way to change the Meteor's one, nor to disable Blaze.

Still I experienced a side effect: While trying to use third party framework such as ionicframework, some directives are using the `{{}}` delimiters within their own code. It means replacing `{{}}` with `[[]]` simply broke some other part of the project…

- A brute force fix would be to search and replace all the {{}} occurrences to [[]] using a preprocessor.
- A workaround would be to manually wrap or replace the non working directive with code I know.

Both seems cumbersome… I wish to be able to change the start and end symbols only on my packages, but is this feasible ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is a very annoying thing...

AngularJS is amazing for letting you do that but Meteor does not.

In the meantime, there are a lot of packages that developers wrote that take care of that for you, Ionic for example:
https://github.com/Urigo/meteor-ionic

Another possible solution is to use Gulp or Grunt or create a task that scans all templates in your Meteor project and changes them to [[ ]]

Of course the best solution will be to be able to import bower packages as they are into Meteor and to be able to add them as is.

Here are two issue related to that that you can follow and +1 them:

https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/2765

https://github.com/mquandalle/meteor-bower/issues/30

Comment: I'm using your meteor-ionic package but still have [this issue](http://github.com/Xample/sidemenu-meteor/issues/3)